# how to pattern match here with table name with local variable

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I'm getting error can't do pattern matching for `mobile_sim_sl` and `W_sim_sl`.

`mobile_sim_sl` is column name and `w_sim_sl` is local variable having same value as column name.

```
SELECT USER_ID, MOBILE_SIM_SL
INTO   STRICT W_USER_ID, W_MOBILE_SIM_SL
FROM   MOBILEUSERS
WHERE  ENTITY_CODE = P_ENTITY_CODE
AND    IMEI_NUMBER = P_IMEI
AND    MOBILE_SIM_SL LIKE '|| W_SIM_SL||';
```

Comment: Why have you tagged both Oracle and PostgreSQL? Please only tag the RDBMS you are actually using, and include the full error message you are getting, and enough code and data to reproduce the problem (see [mre]).

Comment: And what is the error you're getting? And you should write LIKE '%'||w_sim_sl||'%' instead of what you have.

Comment: Is this meant to be `PLSQL`? Or which programming language do you use to provide variable data?